# MOSFET circuit: output connected to both 0 and 1

Tags: transistors, mosfet, circuit-analysis, cmos

In this circuit when A = 0 and B = 1 (or when A = 1 and B = 0), the OUT wire is connected both to high voltage (1) from the power supply and to ground (0) at the same time, what would be the output in this case? Would it be 1 OR 0 = 1, or the 1 will get divided by 2 and output half the voltage from the power supply, or ground will cancel the high voltage so the output will be 0?
[image]

Comment: If both top and bottom MOSFETs are on at the same time, you will have shoot-through, which involves high currents, and may damage your circuit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In logic circuits only VDD or 0 are valid. Any middle point might lead to undefined states or long times to decide where to go (I think it's called metastability).

In this case, if both are shorted the output will go to whichever MOS has the lowest "ron". In principle, you might imagine a poorly defined voltage divider between both "ron" of the PMOS and the NMOS. I.e., I think this circuit is useless.

Comment: so the output should never be connected to both Vdd and ground, right?

Comment: @oabdullae correct, otherwise I wouldn't know what the purpose for such a logic gate is.

Comment: If both top and bottom mosfets are on at the same time, what you have is shoot-through, which involves very high currents which may damage your circuit.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy yeah I realize it now, thanks